# How to render two event listeners on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my rails app, I have a page where I need to display or hide divs based on a select option. This needs to happen to two seperate divs in my app and so I tried using two jquery event listeners to achieve this. I dont really understand javacript so I am struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong. The problem is, only one event listener can work at a time and not both event listeners. 
This is the code in my js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('select[name="lesson[lesson_type]"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;
},false);
function changeEventHandler(event) {
    if(event.target.value === "physical" ) {
      hiddenDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    }
    else {
        hiddenDiv.style.display='none';
    }
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
  document.querySelector('select[name="lesson[course_id]"]').onchange=changeEventHandler;
},false);
function changeEventHandler(event) {
   var course_status = $('#lesson_course_id option:selected').attr('course_type');

    if(course_status == "physical" ) {
      $(".vimeo_link_display").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".vimeo_link_display").show();
    }
}
```

These are the two separate drop-downs in the page

```
   <%= f.input :lesson_type, label: t(".lesson_type") %>
   <%= f.association :course, collection: current_academy.courses.collect { |u| [u.title, u.id, { course_type: u.course_type }] }, prompt: t("select") %>
```

This is the generated html for the first select in the js

```
<select class="form-control enum optional form-control" 
  name="lesson[lesson_type]" id="lesson_lesson_type"><option value="">
  </option> <option selected="selected" value="video">video</option> 
  <option value="podcast">podcast</option> <option 
  value="physical">Physical</option>
</select>
```

The other one has this generated html

```
<select class="form-control select required" name="lesson[course_id]" 
  id="lesson_course_id"><option value="">Vælg</option> <option 
  course_type="online" value="27">Lov om ansættelsesklausuler</option> 
  <option course_type="online" value="54">Skat: 
   Omstrukturering</option> 
  <option course_type="online" value="154">1min couse</option> <option 
  course_type="podcast" value="157">Ransack 101</option> <option 
  course_type="physical" value="158">Physical Course Test </option>
 </select>
```

Only one of the event works on the page. My aim is to have both working when I select the right values from each dropdown.

Please let me know if you need more code samples.

Comment: Put both of the `onchange` inside of one `DOMContentLoaded` listener?

Comment: Please show what the rendered html looks like

Comment: can you please write it out as a full answer? I am struggling with javascrip @Hodrobond

Comment: Don't put code blobs in comments...edit the question so you can format the code there

Comment: i edited it @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

You onlu need one root listner, combine into one. You can rename `changeEventHandler1` and `changeEventHandler2` to your desired names :)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {

  
 document.querySelector('select[name="lesson[lesson_type]"]').onchange=changeEventHandler1;
},false);
function changeEventHandler1(event) {
    if(event.target.value === "physical" ) {
      hiddenDiv.style.display='inline-block';
    }
    else {
        hiddenDiv.style.display='none';
    }
}

  document.querySelector('select[name="lesson[course_id]"]').onchange=changeEventHandler2;
},false);
function changeEventHandler2(event) {
   var course_status = $('#lesson_course_id option:selected').attr('course_type');

    if(course_status == "physical" ) {
      $(".vimeo_link_display").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".vimeo_link_display").show();
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working. In my console there appears to be a syntax error with your solution around changeeventhandler2 "false" text

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.you-select-tag').change(function(){
    $('.div1-to-hide').hide(); # or .show();
    $('.div2-to-hide').hide(); # or .show();
  }
}
```

Comment: i have to different select tags

Comment: So what's the problem applying it to the other one?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.